# How to save a file using GNU Nano?

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I use Termux and GNU nano to edit program text but I don't know how to save it from Nano. Normally in Nano I press shift + O but with Android (I use Samsung S8) the ctrl + O instead prints the char O.

How should I save and exit Nano?

Comment: Are you using a virtual or a physical keyboard?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Virtual

Comment: Try pressing **O** while holding down **Volume-**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can exit by using (ctrl + o) not (shift + o)

Tip. In termux use vim instead. 
not because of "text editor wars" but it is painful to send ctrl and shift keys even with modified keyboards similar to [hacker's keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.pocketworkstation.pckeyboard&hl=en)